# Remove button box-shadow in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button with the class `btn` of bootstrap and after clicking on it, it displays a blue border:

```
<button id="userButton" (click)="onMenu()" class="btn"></button>
```

```css
.test {
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="userButton" (click)="onMenu()" class="btn test"></button>
```

but it keeps appearing. Any idea?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the outline? It is there in order to help keyboard navigation by outlining the element that is currently selected.

Comment: The outline was just a test. I just want to remove the border after clicking but I am not able

Comment: which version of bootstrap ? V3 or V4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blue outline is probably caused by the `:focus` selector on Bootstrap's `.btn` class. Add it to the `.test` class and it *should* work:

```css
.test:focus {
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="userButton" (click)="onMenu()" class="btn test"></button>
```

Answer (score -3):

```css
.test {
  border-color: hidden;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="userButton" (click)="onMenu()" class="btn test"></button>
```

Are you trying to get rid of that border?

> border-color: hidden